# Using libvirt within Docker container

Tags: docker, qemu, libvirt

I am looking to perform a simple test on my VM and see how it behaves within a container and I want to test this using libvirt and QEMU/KVM. I have a domain .xml file that runs the VM just fine on a bare metal server but I am running into issues using libvirt within the container.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -qy \
 && apt-get upgrade -qy \
 && apt-get install -y \
    bridge-utils \
    iproute2 \
    python3-ipy \
    socat \
    qemu-kvm \
    libvirt-daemon-system \
    libvirt-clients \
    virtinst \
    bridge-utils \
    iptables \
    iproute2 \
    dnsmasq \
    vim \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY *.qcow2 /
COPY *.xml /
```

I successfully create a simple image from this Dockerfile running `sudo docker build . -t foo` and to run the container I use `sudo docker run -i --privileged -t --rm foo /bin/bash`. This executes fine but once I am inserted into my containers shell, libvirt is giving me some issues. I am using a confirmed working libvirt domain XML file but when going to define it I get these errors in virsh:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

On a normal environment not nested or containerized it's easier to debug issues with libvirt, usually the daemon is not enabled or running, in the case of a container I am unsure of how to exactly fix the issue. When I check the status of libvirt's daemon, I get this message

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

I assume I should be passing some arguments when running the container that has to do with my network?

Comment: There is no service manager (like systemd) running inside the container. If you want to start libvirtd you need to start it manually (e.g, via the `CMD` statement in a Dockerfile), and when it exits your container would exit.

Comment: ...but a Docker container is itself an isolated environment (and if you're using Docker Desktop or similar tools it is actually inside a virtual machine); it might not make sense to run a virtualization framework there.  This tool might need to run directly on the host.

Comment: It's not as crazy as you might think; there are a number of reasons you might *want* to run libvirt inside a container. The [kubevirt](https://kubevirt.io) project does this, for example, and it allows your vm to access the same network environment that is visible to containerized workloads.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment, here's a basic Dockerfile for running a containerized libvirt:

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
        bridge-utils \
        dmidecode \
        dnsmasq \
        ebtables \
        iproute2 \
        iptables \
        libvirt-clients \
        libvirt-daemon-system \
        ovmf \
        qemu-efi \
        qemu-kvm \
        tini \
        && \
    apt-get clean

RUN sed -i '/^#stdio_handler/ a\stdio_handler = "file"' /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

COPY config/pools/* /etc/libvirt/storage/
COPY config/networks/* /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/
RUN mkdir -p /etc/libvirt/storage/autostart /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/autostart && \
    for pool in /etc/libvirt/storage/*.xml; do \
        ln -sf "../${pool##*/}" /etc/libvirt/storage/autostart/; \
    done && \
    for net in /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/*.xml; do \
        ln -sf "../${net##*/}" /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/autostart/; \
    done

CMD ["/usr/bin/tini", "/usr/sbin/libvirtd"]
```

In `config/pools/default.xml` I have:

```
<pool type='dir'>
  <name>default</name>
  <target>
    <path>/var/lib/libvirt/images</path>
  </target>
</pool>
```

And in `config/networks/default.xml` I have:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.10' end='192.168.122.200'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

If I build an image `libvirtd` from this `Dockerfile` and run it like this:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v /tmp/libvirt:/run/libvirt \
  --privileged \
  --name libvirt \
  --device /dev/kvm \
  -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup \
  libvirtd
```

Then I can do things like this:

```
$ virsh -c qemu:///system'?socket=/tmp/libvirt/libvirt-sock' net-list
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes
```

Or even:

```
export LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI='qemu:///system?socket=/tmp/libvirt/libvirt-sock'

virsh vol-create-as --pool default jammy 653M
virsh vol-upload jammy \
  jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img \
  --pool default
virt-install -n jammy -r 4096 \
  --disk pool=default,size=10,backing_store=jammy,backing_format=qcow2 \
  --network network=default \
  --os-variant ubuntujammy \
  --import
```